# Bubble sorting in C

Tags: algorithm, c, sorting

I've been into algorithms lately, so I wanted to apply a simple algorithm using a language of my choice, which was C in this case.

I've implemented the bubblesort algorithm (for strings) in a simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_NAMES (5)

void sort(char ** sorted, char ** strs, const size_t size, const bool ascending) { // using the bubble sort algorithm
    sorted[0] = strs[0];
    char ** f = strs;
    for(int u=0; u < size; ++u) {
        for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
            if (strcmp(sorted[i], f[i+1]) <= 0) { // sorted[i] is first
                sorted[i+1] = f[i+1];
            } else { // f[i+1] is first
                char *temp = f[i]; // just in case f == sorted, they'll point to the same thing ..
                sorted[i] = f[i+1];
                sorted[i+1] = temp;
            }
        }
        f = sorted;
    }
    if (!ascending) { // reverse it !
        char *reversed[size]; // temporarily
        int i1 = 0, i2 = size - 1;
        while (i1 < size && i2 >= 0) { // one condition would do. Only to be thread-safe
            reversed[i1] = sorted[i2];
            i1++;i2--;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            sorted[i] = reversed[i]; // putting it to sorted
    }
}

void printNames(char * q, char ** names, int num) {
    printf("\t%s\n", q);
    for(int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
        printf("%d: %s\n", i+1, names[i]);
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
        printf("=");
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char * names[] = {
        "This should be Second",
        "This should be First",
        "This should be before the last",
        "Wait .. That's the last!",
        "This should be Third"
    };

    char *names_ordered[NUM_NAMES];
    printNames("Original", names, NUM_NAMES);
    sort(names_ordered, names, NUM_NAMES, true);
    printNames("Ascending", names_ordered, NUM_NAMES);
    sort(names_ordered, names, NUM_NAMES, false);
    printNames("Descending", names_ordered, NUM_NAMES);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know if there's a problem with the sort function, especially in the reversing part, because I think that that's not efficient.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Reversing is not very efficient indeed (*but who cares about an extra linear pass when bubble sort itself is quadratic?*). I would rather account for the requested order during the comparison:

```
result = strcmp(...);
if (!ascending)
    result = -result;
```

- Initialization `f = strs` is very confusing, because later on `f` is reinitialized to `sorted`. I'd initialize it to `sorted` always, as close to use as possible.

Something like

```
for(int u=0; u < size; ++u) {
    char ** f = sorted;
    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
        ...
    }
}
```

- One-character names, especially unmotivated like `f`, `u` and `q` should be avoided. You really have to figure out *what* the variable is, and name it accordingly.

Comment: I get all your points, except for the initialization issue. What's wrong with it ? _f_ is the string array to order, and since _sorted_ is empty at first, I can't **always** make _f_ point to _sorted_ ..

Comment: Also, I tried `result = -result` and it doesn't seem to work for some reason ..

Comment: It is confusing: glancing at the code I see that `f` sometimes points into `strs`, and sometimes into `sorted`, and I need a mental effort to realize that pointing into `strs` is bogus. Now, `sorted` is __not__ empty. You just have `sorted[0] = strs[0]`. Regarding `result` tweak not working I have no say. Some debugging is in order.

Comment: Best case Bubble is linear. So still a useful function if you know your data is nearly or probably already sorted. Or when the data set is small bubble is efficient because of the low overhead.

Comment: @LokiAstari Even better, you can abort bubble sort at any time if a roughly sorted list is acceptable.

Answer (score 6):

Small details:

- It's confusing that you define `NUM_NAMES` as a macro and then `names` as a variable.  Either define two variables or two macros, but keep those two items together.
- If you use `const`, use it everywhere (`printNames` too).

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort is well described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort. The optimized form remembers the last exchange made and notes that all higher elements are sorted already. Bubble sort is an inefficient amgorithm but easy to implement. At worst it runs in O(n^2). In pseudo code:

```
sort (A, n)     // bubble sort array A[0..n-1]
int j, k, l;

k= n-1;         // k holds position of last interchange. All higher elements are sorted.
while (k > 0)
{
    l= 0;
    for (j=0; j < k; j++)
    {
        if (A[j] > A[j+1])
        {
            tmp   = A[j];
            A[j]  = A[j+1];
            A[j+1]= tmp;
            l= j;
        }
    }
    k= l;
}
```

**EDIT**
Applying this to the sort algorithm and making the sort more generic, results in how I would write it:

```
/* Sort unsorted array 'unsorted' of pointers to objects into a sorted array 'sorted'.
 * 'size' has the number of elements in 'unsorted'. Array 'sorted' is assumed to be large enough
 * to hold the sorted result. The arrays are 'pointers to objects' and the result has only
 * the pointers to the original objects, but now in a sorted order. The objects themselves
 * are not copied. Function 'cmp' provided by the caller compares two objects.
 */
void sort(void **sorted, void **unsorted, const size_t size, const int ascending, int (*cmp)(void *, void *))
{
    size_t i, lastXchg, thisXchg;

    for (i=0; i < size; i++)    // first copy the unsorted array to the result array
        sorted[i]= unsorted[i];

    lastXchg= size-1;           // lastXchg remembers the last exchange; all higher elements are sorted
    while (lastXchg > 0)        // now  bubble sort the result array
    {
        thisXchg= 0;                        // remember the last exchange this round
        for (i=0; i < lastXchg; i++)
        {
            int result= cmp(sorted[i], sorted[i+1]);
            if (( ascending && result > 0)
            ||  (!ascending && result < 0))
            {
                void *tmp= sorted[i];
                sorted[i]= sorted[i+1];
                sorted[i+1]= tmp;
                thisXchg= i;
            }
        }
        lastXchg= thisXchg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't think this is a good answer. You make the same mistakes as the O.P. did, regarding short and cryptic variable names, and you don't even explain what you have done to improve the code.

Comment: @Ismael-Miguel, algorithms may require explanation very much beyond comments in code. Thereto papers are written. Further, short variable names, in cases, bring more clarity of the algorithm's steps than long variabe names. I do use the convenion though, that such algorithms should fit on one screen to give the reader the overview. Names like `i` and `j` are not cryptic; they are clearly integer indexes. The code improvement is showing the O.P. how to remember the last interchange (`k`) as all higher elements are already sorted.

Comment: Instead of `l`, try `last`. Instead of `A`, try `numbers` or something. Instead of `j`, try `i` (since it is in a `for` loop). Instead of `k` try .... I don't know, what does `k` do? `"k holds position of last interchange. All higher elements are sorted."` --> Is that the last sorted index?

Comment: Yes, I could have started the variables at `i`. `A` is a generic name standing for Array. For details of the algorithm, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort, under optimized.

Comment: @Ismael-Miguel, I took your comments to heart and attempted to improve my answer. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: So much better now! I finally feel happy for your answer. The only thing I would change is that `if`, to put it all in the same line. Since you have that giant function declaration, you can have a smaller `if`. Other than that, you deserve an upvote!

Comment: I deliberately put the if on two lines to show how the conditions are reversed.

Comment: Then I would say to remove the spaces between the `||` and the parenthesys (misspelled?), to be a tad better looking. You can disregard if you wish. One thing that ticks me is that you aren't attributing a value to your variables on the top. `lastXchg` would love this and you would cut one line.